# Assertion error message in jmeter dashboard report

Tags: jmeter, assertions

I am creating jmeter dashboard report using a .jmx file, It's working fine but I am getting on response error code in report, not able to get assertion error message in the report.

[image: I am getting this type of error section in report]

Comment: You're getting 400s and a 403.  Did you try running the jmx urls by hand?

Comment: Yes, I was expecting the same error codes (400 and 403) but along with it I have added response assertions in which using bean shell script, I am asserting response values and on failure giving my own assertion failure message. I want to print that message.