# How to display assertion error message in dashboard report?

Tags: jmeter, report, dashboard

The question was already posted by Chintamani [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44518179/assertion-error-message-in-jmeter-dashboard-report) however it has not been answered.
I'm trying to get the details of my error through the generated dashboard report by JMeter but it's not detailed out in the report. It just indicates that an assertion failed.

[image]

Rather than just indicating **Assertion Failed** in the Type of error. I would want for the report to display the custom response assertion error message that I indicated in the response assertion. I hope someone can help. Thanks!

[image]

### **EDITS:**

I have replicated the issue here. It still indicating assertion failed. Not sure what I'm missing here. Also, I am using the updated JMeter version 5.2.1.

[image]

This is my result save configuration on my simple data writer.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for properties `jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false`
This should be equal to true or just remove/comment before running again.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue using latest stable [JMeter version 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html):

[image]

According to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/) you should be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to JMeter 5.2.1 (or whatever is the latest stable JMeter version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) and the issue will go away.

If you're using the latest version already it might be the case you're looking into "old" results, re-run your test providing [`-f` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) so JMeter would overwrite the previous .jtl results file and the dashboard folder with the new results

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have edited my question on my findings upon replicating the issue. I've tried copying what you have done. However, I'm still getting Assertion failed as the message. I've also added save configuration. Might be missing some settings there.

Comment: Remove all the listeners from your test plan, the [Listeners don't add any value and only consume system resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/). You should be running your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui), if you want you can [generate the HTML reporting dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_after_load_test) at the same time like `jmeter -n -f -t test.jmx -l result.jtl -e -o /path/to/dashboard`

Comment: I see now the root cause of the issue. There is this line in the user.properties "jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false". That's why the message is not displaying.